# Pycharm and UTF-8 in code

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, pycharm

When I try to run this code:

```
with open('scraped.csv', 'w') as dump:
        writer = csv.writer(dump, delimiter='ę', escapechar='\\',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        writer.writerow(('author', 'ups', 'downs',
                         'score', 'sub_name', 'replys',
                         'created_utc', 'pulled down at'))
```

in PyCharm, I get the following error

```
  File ..., line 38, in <module>
'created_utc', 'pulled down at'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0119' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is PyCharm not able to support UTF-8 in files? Or am I missing a setting somewhere. The same file builds in Sublime.

Comment: I believe the `csv` module specifies that files must be opened in binary mode.

Comment: @MarkRansom: on Python 3, it should be a text mode with `newline=''` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had a similar error before in PyCharm, I think it is something to do with the encoding detection selecting 'ascii' rather than UTF8. There is however a simple work around:

```
with open('scraped.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') as dump:
    writer = csv.writ...
```

The encoding option will force the file to load UTF8.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian where? for what reason?

Comment: If explicit encoding is not provided then `open()` uses [`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding).

Comment: The CSV module documentation for Python 3 require that file objects passed to csv.writer are opened with `newline=''`. See http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer and the accompanying footnote.

Comment: In particular, my terminal sets `LANG="en_AU.UTF-8"` which PyCharm does not seem to - this might explain the difference in defaults. Running `LANG="en_AU.UTF-8" python3.3 unicodecsv.py` from within PyCharm allows the original code to run correctly (although explicitly setting `encoding` is a better solution)

Comment: Also, adding `LANG=en_AU.UTF-8` to Settings->Project Settings->Console->Python Console->Environment variables modifies the PyCharm console settings

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Changing the encoding fixed it. It's very bizarre that PyCharm doesn't use UTF-8 by default, but I assume this behavior is for Python 2 developers.